SQLalchemy выдаёт _run_ddl_visitor
Я написал следующий код:
import configparser
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Boolean, ForeignKey, Table
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

engine = None

# getting type of database
TypeOfDb = config.get("database", "type")
if TypeOfDb == "sqlite3":
    # getting name
    name = config.get("database", "name")
    # string of connection
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"sqlite:///./{name}.db"
    engine = create_engine(
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
    )
elif TypeOfDb == "psql":
    # name of DB
    name = config.get("database", "name")
    password = config.get("database", "password")
    user = config.get("database", "user")
    host = config.get("database", "host")

    # string of connection
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{name}"
    engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

# define tables in the database
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True)
    verificated = Column(Boolean)

class Store(Base):
    __tablename__ = "store"

    UserId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    INN = Column(String, unique=True)
    store_id = Column(Integer, unique=True)


class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "thing"

    StoreId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    category = Column(String)
    price = Column(Integer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
else:
    SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    db = SessionLocal()

Файл config.ini:
[database]
type = "sqlite3"
name = "main"
password = ""
user = ""
host = ""
[shop]
name = "SomeShop"
valute = "RUB"
lan = "RU"

При запуске файла с кодом напрямую появляется ошибка:

bind._run_ddl_visitor(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_run_ddl_visitor'**

Вот здесь полный трейс ошибки:
https://pastebin.com/B2M0CTuY

Приведите полный стек-трейс ошибки, а не отрывок.

А вообще вот, например https://stackoverflow.com/a/74000761/8324991

добавил вот так:
    with engine.begin() as conn:
        conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
        conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
```, теперь у меня такая ошибка: https://pastebin.com/0tV2GTw1

Пожалуйста, размещайте текст ошибки, а не ссылки. Со временем они исчезнут.

Все добавления делайте прямо в вопрос и текстом.
